# Something is wrong with my Jukebox. What should I do?

Tags: audio-player

Something is wrong with my Jukebox. My sampler is not working right.:

"zs = _sample(zs, labels, sampling_kwargs, [None, None, top_prior], [2], hps)"

leads to

"AssertionError Traceback (most recent call last)
in ()
16 x = load_prompts(audio_files, duration, hps)
17 zs = top_prior.encode(x, start_level=0, end_level=len(priors), bs_chunks=x.shape[0])
---> 18 zs = _sample(zs, labels, sampling_kwargs, [None, None, top_prior], [2], hps)
19 else:
20 raise ValueError(f'Unknown sample mode {sample_hps.mode}.')"

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jukebox/prior/conditioners.py in forward(self, pos_start, pos_end)
89 # Check if [pos_start,pos_end] in [pos_min, pos_max)
90 assert len(pos_start.shape) == 2, f"Expected shape with 2 dims, got {pos_start.shape}"
---> 91 assert (self.pos_min <= pos_start).all() and (pos_start < self.pos_max).all(), f"Range is [{self.pos_min},{self.pos_max}), got {pos_start}"
92 pos_start = pos_start.float()
93 if pos_end is not None:

AssertionError: Range is [786744.0,26460000.0), got tensor([[240.]], device='cuda:0')"

and

"KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
16   x = load_prompts(audio_files, duration, hps)
17   zs = top_prior.encode(x, start_level=0, end_level=len(priors), bs_chunks=x.shape[0])
---> 18   zs = _sample(zs, labels, sampling_kwargs, [None, None, top_prior], [2], hps)
19 else:
20   raise ValueError(f'Unknown sample mode {sample_hps.mode}.')

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/jukebox/sample.py in sample_single_window(zs, labels, sampling_kwargs, level, prior, start, hps)
58     empty_cache()
59
---> 60     max_batch_size = sampling_kwargs['max_batch_size']
61     del sampling_kwargs['max_batch_size']
62

KeyError: 'max_batch_size'"

Comment: Please update your post with minimum reproducible code and describe what you have tried so far

Comment: Okay, but what's my minimum reproducible code?

Comment: The minimum amount of code someone else will need to reproduce the error.